# rendering simple_form errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have list with posts (pages#home), on click I open list with comments (posts#show), where I declare variable @feed_items. In the end of the comments I have simple_form for new comment (comments#create). Problem: if error occuring on submit button, I need to render existed list with comments and form with errors.
I'm trying in comments#create:

```
if @comment.save
  ...
else
  render 'posts/show'
end
```

but in this case variable @feed_items isn't declared because method posts#show didn't called. When I trying to write redirect_to I see list with comments but without error messages. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake people do. The `render` method only selects the view to display, and the `redirect_to` method executes the action of the redirection again.
When there are errors, you call the `render` method to select the view you want to display, and you have to manually assign all the instance variables this view need to work out.
Check `Section 2.3.2` from the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

In your case it would be something like this:

```
if @comment.save
  ...
else
  # Populate the @feed_items in here again
  render 'posts/show'
end
```